# Не работает swipe между TabHost с scroll-виджетами

Tags: android, activity, swipe

Имеется 4 Activity с различной разметкой. Когда они "обычные", , свайп работает. Если делаю extends от ListActivity или же добавляю в резметку  чтобы на странице можно было скролить - свайп на этих активностях перестает работать. Как это можно побороть? Заранее спасибо!

Реализация свайпа ниже:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {


    private GestureDetectorCompat mGestueDetector;

    public TabHost tabHost;
    private int tab_counter = 4;    //number of the tabs


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //gestue detector attaching
        mGestueDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);


        // получаем TabHost
        this.tabHost = getTabHost();

        // инициализация была выполнена в getTabHost
        // метод setup вызывать не нужно

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Home");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, home_activity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Friends");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, contacts_activity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Map");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, map_activity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag4");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Scan");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, scanner_activity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        //Setting listener to the tab events (gestue detecting)
        tabHost.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                mGestueDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        contactDBLoad();
    }



.....

        @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        Log.d("FLYING","MOTION");

        int current_tab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        float sensitvity = 50;

        //if - right // else - left
        if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity){
            /* viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slide_in_right);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slide_out_left);
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();*/
            if(current_tab!=(tab_counter-1))
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(current_tab+1);
        }
        else if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){
            /*viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);
            viewFlipper.showNext();*/
            if(current_tab!=0)
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(current_tab-1);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Вы пользуютесь тем, чем не следует вообще, давно уже есть `ViewPager` и `PagerAdapter`, позволяющий свайпить `View` или `Fragment`, `TabHost` уровень Android 2.0

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Но могу ли я использовать их для SDK 22 ?

Comment: Для высоких LEVEL API на каком угодно SDK

Answer (score 2):

Не используйте `TabHost`. Это вымершая технология. Используйте `ViewPager` в связке с `TabLayout`.

Comment: Перешел на ViewPager, всё получилось, всё работает как надо! Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Eugen Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа).